# Grab the text content of the same element in all tabs and paste them into popup.html - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to create a chrome extension that goes through the tabs, grab the elements I want and paste them back to popup.html.

I successfully sent the elements from content script to bg.js:

Content script

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0].innerHTML);
```

Background script

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse){
    var companynames = [];
    companynames.push(response);
    console.log(companynames)

})
```

I saw the variables in background view. However, instead of seeing an array of all my variables, I see a lot of arrary and each array contains one variable from each page.

How can I group them together?

Comment: Vote to typo, you should use `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` rather than `OnMessage`

Comment: Thnaks for your help! Now I get the variables in bg.js. However, what if I open multiple pages and I want to group all the variables sent from content script? Let me adjust my question above.

Comment: Ok I solved my own problem. Just put var companynames = []; before the chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener thing.